# Change a line property

Tags: vb.net, 2d, gdi+, graphic

I'm new in GDI +. Can someone help me to finish my task?

This is my code:

```
Private Sub DrawLines(ByVal g As Graphics)
    For Each line As Line In Me.lines
        g.DrawLine(Pens.White, line.Start, line.End)
    Next line
End Sub
```

The line was drawn on picturebox object.

Are the line was drawn is will be an object ? If yes, how to enable some event like click or others ? how to change a property of the line ?

This [Image](http://tinypic.com/r/zx371z/8) is shown if a mouse cursor in a line area, the line can change the color into red.

My question: How can i do this? Detect, retrieve line area and change a color of line

Can anyone give me a simple logic?

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think GDI+ gives you line objects like that, but you can create a collection of GraphicPath objects that might let you do what you want. You could certainly detect click events (as shown below). As for changing the visible properties of a line, I believe you would have to call a Paint method and use a Pen object with different properties.

In this example, the DrawLines method creates a GraphicsPath for each of the lines and then calls PictureBox_Paint to update the screen. You could change the color or width of MyPen and call the paint method again to redraw the lines differently.

The PictureBox1_MouseDown method uses IsOutlineVisible to determine if one of the paths was clicked.

```
'Collection of paths to hold references to the "Lines" and a pen for drawing them
Private MyPaths As New List(Of Drawing2D.GraphicsPath)
Private MyPen As New Pen(Color.Red, 4)


Private Sub DrawLines()

    'Loop over the lines and add a path for each to the collection
    For Each Ln As Line In Lines
        Dim MyPath As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
        MyPath.AddLine(Ln.Start, Ln.End)
        MyPaths.Add(MyPath)
    Next

    'Call method to draw the paths with the specified pen
    PictureBox_Paint(Me, New System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs(Me.PictureBox1.CreateGraphics, Me.PictureBox1.ClientRectangle))
End Sub


Public Sub PictureBox_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint

    For Each Pth As Drawing2D.GraphicsPath In MyPaths
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(MyPen, Pth)
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown

    'Create a Graphics object for PictureBox (needed for the IsOutlineVisible method)
    Dim Gr As Graphics = Me.PictureBox1.CreateGraphics

    'Loop over paths in collection and check if mouse click was on top of one
    For Each Pth As Drawing2D.GraphicsPath In MyPaths
        If Pth.IsOutlineVisible(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y, MyPen, Gr) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Path was clicked", "Click")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```